# Getting 3G instead of 4G (LTE)

Tags: usb-modem, modem, 3g, 4g, wwan

I've got a **Sierra Wireless Airprime MC7354** module, supplying a cellular communication to my x86 - running **Ubuntu Server 14.04**.

By default, on module boot, it searches for an LTE network connection, and if fails - it falls back to 3G.

Though I'm supplied with several Sim cards, from different providers, all are LTE compatible (works great on my phone) - *I can only get a 3G network with Ubuntu (no LTE)*.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: MC7354 supports only this LTE bands and is marketed for Americas region: B2, B4, B5, B13, B17, B25. This is the compatibility that matters. You may need this: http://source.sierrawireless.com/resources/airprime/software/linux-qmi-sdk-software-04,-d-,00,-d-,04/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **CelticWarrior**:

The MC7354 supports only specified LTE bands and is marketed for Americas region: B2, B4, B5, B13, B17, B25.